# Normal distribution of a random variable proof

Tags: probability-distributions, proof-writing, solution-verification, normal-distribution

Suppose that $X$ is a random variable that follows a chi-square distribution with df $= 1$. Now suppose $W$ is another random variable such that its value is dependent on $X$. In particular a value of $X$ is sampled and a fair coin is flipped. If the coin lands on "tails", then $W = -\sqrt{X}$. Otherwise if "heads", then $W = \sqrt{X}$. Prove that $W$ is a standard normal variable.

Hint: Consider two cases for $w$.

My attempt:

When $w \geq 0$:

$F_W(w) = P(W \leq w) = P(\sqrt{X} \leq w) = P(X \leq w^2) = 2P(X \leq w^2) - 1$

We have that $F_W(w) = 2\int_{0}^{w^2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi xe^x}} \,dx - 1$

So, $f_W(w) = \frac{d}{dw}(2\int_{0}^{w^2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi xe^x}} \,dx - 1) = 4(\frac{e^{\frac{-w^2}{2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}})$

When $w < 0$:

$F_W(w) = P(W \leq w) = P(-\sqrt{X} \leq w) = P(\sqrt{X} \geq w) = 1 - P(\sqrt{X} \leq w) = -2P(X \leq w^2)$

We have that $F_W(w) = -2\int_{0}^{w^2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi xe^x}} \,dx$

So, $f_W(w) = \frac{d}{dw}(-2\int_{0}^{w^2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi xe^x}} \,dx) = -4(\frac{e^{\frac{-w^2}{2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}})$

So $W$ follows a standard normal distribution.

QED.

Is this proof correct? Did I make a mistake (especially in case 2? Is $P(-\sqrt{X} \leq w) = P(\sqrt{X} \leq w)$?). Any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: You did not apply the defnition of $W$ correctly. For example, in case 1, $P(W \leq w)=\frac  1 2+\frac   12 P(\sqrt X \leq w)$.

Comment: Ok so there are several mistakes here.
First of all, when $w < 0$, $\mathbb{P}(\sqrt{X} \ge w) = 1$ so you can not have $\mathbb{P}(-\sqrt{X} \le w) = \mathbb{P}(\sqrt{X} \ge w)$. 
Second of all, in your first case, even when $w \ge 0$ you can have $W \le w$ when $W = - \sqrt{X}$ (this is where the $\frac{1}{2}$ in @KaviRamaMurthy answer comes from). You need to break down the value of $W$ in two pieces in the two cases (the second one, where $w \le 0$, is easier).

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Why do we add $1/2$? Is it because of the coin toss?

Comment: Yes, you have to take coin toss in to account.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Would adding the half really change much though? After all, the differentiation bit should eliminate all constants...

Comment: Differentiatin does not eliminate the factor of $\frac 1 2 $ in the second term.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I meant all constants that are being summed...

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Also, what would the four different cases be then?

Comment: @Gâteau-Gallois What are the four cases then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$w > 0$:
$$ P(W \le w) = P(W = - \sqrt{X}, W \le w) + P(W = \sqrt{X}, W \le w) = P(W = -\sqrt{X}) + \frac{1}{2}P(\sqrt{x} \le w) = \frac12 + \frac{1}{2}F_X(w^2), $$
Differentiating gives you the right solution in this case.
Then for $w \le 0$,
$$ P(W \le w) = P(W = -\sqrt{X}, - \sqrt{X} \le w) = \frac{1}{2} P(X > w^2), $$
and once again, differentiating gives you the answer.

Comment: Wouldn't the second case $w \leq 0$ produce a result that is negative?

Comment: Actually, nevermind, thanks!